# Binding AttachedProperty to object's property

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, binding, styles

I'm trying to bind the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties to my custom X and Y properties, with no success, I'm using the following XAML.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type layout:BankBaseControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type layout:BankBaseControl}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Marker}" >
                    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="{Binding Width}"
                                     Height="{Binding Height}"
                                     Canvas.Left="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     Canvas.Top="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The style is applied correctly (Width and Height binding works properly), but the attached properties don't seem to be looking at the X and Y values. I tried doing this binding from code with:

```
SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, new Binding("X")
    { Source = Marker,  Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

And it worked, but I'd much like to do it from XAML.

EDIT:
I also tried changing the bindings in XAML to `Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100"`, but no luck, the ellipse would still show on coords 0,0.

Comment: pls confirm that you have XProperty and YProperty dependency properties defined in your Control properly

Comment: are the x and y properties dependency properties?

Comment: as far as  iknow for `{Binding}` extension to work, Source has to be Dependency Property.

Comment: Did you get any binding errors in console, you are using Source = Marker in code but not in xaml.

Comment: X and Y are regular (non Dependency) properties on my Marker object, their values are set correctly. No errors on console.

Comment: I also tried changing the bindings in XAML to `Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100"`, but no luck, the ellipse would still show on coords 0,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have isn't valid. Your Ellipse is not a child of a Canvas, so the Canvas attached properties are not going to be used. Your Ellipse is a child of the ContentPresenter, which is a child of your BankBaseControl.

You would need to set the attached properties on BankBaseControl, assuming it's hosted in a Canvas panel like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type layout:BankBaseControl}">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}, Path=Marker.X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}, Path=Marker.Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type layout:BankBaseControl}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Marker}" >
                    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```